# google apspot xmpp send fail. is this bug?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, xmpp

```
    JID jid = new JID("ad...@host.domain.com"); //success with code
    SUCCESS
    JID jid = new JID("mycomponent.host.domain.com");  //send fail with
    code INVALID_ID    ,but when i try send from gmail OR jabber to
    mycomponent.host.domain.com . it was a success.Is this a bug in google xmpp api?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If 'mycomponent.host.domain.com' really is a valid JID, then this is a bug. Feel free to file it in the issue tracker!

Comment: appreciated for answer. Hope someone can have a look and confirm it's a bug or not..

Answer (score 1):

"mycomponent.host.domain.com" is valid syntactically, both according to [RFC 3920](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3920.html#addressing) as well as according to the new best reference, [draft-ietf-xmpp-address](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-xmpp-address), both of which say that the only required portion of a JID is the domain.  As long as all of the unicode code points in your domain name pass nameprep (i.e., they can be used as an internationalized domain name), this is a bug in the Google API.

Comment: ya man , i think it's a bug. need more people to confirm. i filled and issue 3208. please vote